Unwanted translucent overlay when app loads and when navigating between screens
This happens only in Android - whenever the app loads and when navigating between screens, there is a translucent overlay on top of the screen, that disappears when pressing "Home" button in Android and switching back to the app. Upon debugging, I found that this overlay takes the same colour as what we set in the NavigationContainer. So I tried changing the theme to:
const NewTheme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    background: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
  },
};

Now, the overlay is translucent (yes, reduced opacity weirdly) red. And when I change it to rgb(0, 255, 0), it turns into translucent green. If you see the following images attached, if you focus you can indeed see the outlines of other components within.


The general Navigation Container structure is defined as (Host is from react-native-portalize for the usage of Modals):
const ModalStack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
return <NavigationContainer theme={NewTheme}>
<Host>
<ModalStack.Navigator 
      screenOptions={({ route, navigation }) => ({
        headerShown: false,
        gestureEnabled: true,
        cardOverlayEnabled: true,
        headerStatusBarHeight:
          navigation.getState().routes.findIndex((r) => r.key === route.key) > 0 ? 0 : undefined,
        ...TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS,
      })}>
  <ModalStack.Screen name="Root" component={AnotherNativeNavigator} />
  <ModalStack.Screen name="Webview" component={WebviewScreen} />
  <ModalStack.Screen name="Screen2" component={Screen2} />
  <ModalStack.Screen name="Screen3" component={Screen3} />
</ModalStack.Navigator>
</Host>
</NavigationContainer>

This issue does not appear in iOS.
React Native version: 0.73
@react-navigation/native version: 6.1.9
